# how to automize the running of a command that prompts for user input?

Tags: automation, expect

I have a program that ask for input. For example:

```
$ program arg1 arg2
Enter the value of arg3: foo
Enter the value of arg4: spam
$
```

How can I automatize the running? I suspect the `expect` provide the functionality for that but the following does not work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
spawn "./program arg1 arg2"
expect "Enter the value of arg3:" { send "foo\r" }
expect "Enter the value of arg4:" { send "spam\r" }
interact
```

Does anyone have ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spawn "./program arg1 arg2"` should be `spawn ./program arg1 arg2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it the simplest way possible (without expect): Does this work?

```
program arg1 arg2 <<END
foo
spam
END
```

(or `printf "%s\n" foo spam | program arg1 arg2`)